# problem with extracting data from oracle buckup dbf files

Tags: oracle, backup, dbf

I have dbf files from my client oracle database. Their admin said that is buckup of database. I am trying to opening those files in different editors like open office, excel, dbf manager and others, but it cannot be done because during this action it always says file has incorrect format, or file has incorrect header.

I read a little and it seems that was wrong backup of database or something. I have 7 dbf files and none of them works.

I just want to open those files and make import to csv/excel to export it to new system with sql database

Comment: DBF is a proprietary Oracle format and you won't be able to throw random software packages at the problem and expect them to be able to read the data. You need to install an Oracle RDBMS and add the DBF files to an instance and then export the data.

Comment: Oracle's dbf file format is different from the xBase .dbf file, which is why those tools weren't working.